# Git checkout issue and not able to move to any branch

Tags: git, git-checkout

I want to switch to a branch `qa` that exists on the remote `origin`. I am using `git checkout qa` but it's doing nothing for me, it not move and does not show any sort of results. What is the possible solution to that?

Comment: Please include more information.  There are so many things that could be happening right now.

Comment: Hi I solved my problem by deleting my previous branch and then using git fetch, then I used git checkout qa and it wotrked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see what is going on with `git status`

It will show at least what current branch you are in (you can combine that with `git branch -avv`), and give you a clue as to what state your repo is in.

In your case, there was a local qa branch but without relation to `origin/qa`, not until you deleted your local branch and fetched the remote again.

*Then* a `git checkout qa` was the equivalent of `git checkout -b qa origin/qa`

Comment: Hi I solved my problem by deleting my previous branch and then using git fetch, then I used git checkout qa and it wotrked

Comment: @AliNafeesDhillon OK. I have edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: it was fetched , but I deleted it and fetch it again worked for me

Comment: @AliNafeesDhillon OK, I have edited the answer again, to better reflect your situation